# SqlServer is in script upgrade mode after SP3 installation

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008

This is almost the same question as [SqlServer is in script upgrade mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975286/sqlserver-is-in-script-upgrade-mode)

But i'm hoping to find an answer as every solution there does not work for me.

I installed SQL Server 2008R2 SP3. After the Service Pack update, the service will start, but stop within a few seconds with this error in the errorlog

```
10:53:47.93 spid7s      Error: 5041, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2014-12-02 10:53:47.93 spid7s      MODIFY FILE failed. File 'MSDBLog' does not exist.
2014-12-02 10:53:47.94 spid7s      Error: 912, Severity: 21, State: 2.
2014-12-02 10:53:47.94 spid7s      Script level upgrade for database 'master' failed because upgrade step 'sqlagent100_msdb_upgrade.sql' encountered error 598, state 1, severity 25. This is a serious error condition which might interfere with regular operation and the database will be taken offline. If the error happened during upgrade of the 'master' database, it will prevent the entire SQL Server instance from starting. Examine the previous errorlog entries for errors, take the appropriate corrective actions and re-start the database so that the script upgrade steps run to completion.
2014-12-02 10:53:47.94 spid7s      Error: 3417, Severity: 21, State: 3.
2014-12-02 10:53:47.94 spid7s      Cannot recover the master database. SQL Server is unable to run. Restore master from a full backup, repair it, or rebuild it. For more information about how to rebuild the master database, see SQL Server Books Online.
2014-12-02
```

These are my registry settings:

> HKHKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.I2008\Setup\SQLDataRoot

F:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.I2008\MSSQL

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.I2008\MSSQLServer\DefaultData

K:\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\

As per http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2010/10/27/sql-server-2008-service-fails-to-start-after-applying-service-pack-1.aspx I tried to change the latter path to

F:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.I2008\MSSQL

and I tried

F:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.I2008\MSSQL\Data

, but that does nothing.

On the folder with the MSDB database, these are the permissions:

`SYSTEM: Full controll`

`SQLServerMSSSQLUser$<servername>$<instancename>: Full control`

`Administrators: Full control`

I tried adding the service account that rns the SQL Server instance, but that that didn't work as well.
Also, there is enough space on al harddrives.
What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I found the solution. The file MSDBlog.mdf existed, but the logical name of the file was msdb_log. To solve this:

1. Startup the SQL Server service with the -T902 flag, so it skips the script upgrade.
2. Execute the following script to alter the name, in this case I altered it to 'MSDBLog'because that was the name that was mentioned in the errorlog (see first post):

>

```
USE [msdb]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [msdb] MODIFY FILE (NAME=N'msdb_log', NEWNAME=N'MSDBLog')
GO
```

3. Restart the SQL Server instance